# Importing GRASS

Tags: grass-gis

I tried to run i.atcorr in a system in which GRASS GUI was not installed. I copied all the required libraries to one folder and set environment variable to that location. But while importing raster data "spatialite4.dll missing" from path error message seen. But in the specified path location that DLL exists.

Comment: You haven't stated any platform or versions, but the usual issue for "The system says it doesn't but it does" issue with DLLs is bitwise compatibility -- The DLL is not compatible with the binary, so it is rejected with a "not found" error when in fact it's really a "wrong found first" situation.

Comment: The question of running GRASS modules without installing GRASS has come up before. And I must say that I am perplexed by this idea. I wouldn't expect to be able to run a complex, multi-platform application, with **many** dependencies without it being installed. If there's some administrative limitation, then I think you'll just have to get your system admin to install the application.

Comment: Please check this page: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WinGRASS_errors#GRASS_GIS_installation_.28OSGeo4W_or_standalone.29_fails_with_a_sqlite3_error

Comment: I have run the program on different system without installing entire grass. Only required dlls got copied and set GISDABSE and GISBASE in environment variable and its working fine.But for one system this spatialite4 dll missing error has been observed.My question IS there any grass dependency on spatialite4.dll? how to run grass without modifying existing dll path(which is set in  environment path variable) for any other application. i tried to see whether any conflict with other opensource softwares in the system.I found that qgis and saga gis have been installed in that system.please suggest